# I have an error called CS0117 in unity, how do I fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99o6d.png)

```
[13:09:25] Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.psdimporter@4.0.2\Editor\PSDImporter.cs(593,65): error CS00117: 'TexturePlatformSettingsHelper' does not contain a definition for 'GetBuildTargetName'
```

I imported the lost crypt package from the unity asset store, i upgraded the materials because they we're all pink, then i opened up my project up again and this error happened.How do I fix it?

Comment: Note: StackOverflow discourages screenshots (for many good reasons).  I took the liberty of transcribing the error message.  ALSO: See if this link helps: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1780059/i-am-getting-an-error-message-i-cant-fix.html.  Try updating the 2D PSD Importer.

Comment: Try to clear your package cache and/or make sure all your packages are up-to-date